Rewrite rule for nested URL does end in 404
I am trying to do custom RSS feeds for specific categorys of events in my event calendar on wordpress.
This one does work:
function custom_organizer_feed_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^organizer/([^/]+)/feed/?', 'index.php?organizer_feed_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_organizer_feed_rewrite_rule');

This one does not:
function custom_venue_category_feed_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^events/venues/categorys/superior_category/([^/]+)/feed/?', 'index.php?venue_category_feed_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_venue_category_feed_rewrite_rule');

Is it because it is nested? How can I use this rule - I just want to get the exact category here ([^/]+).

WordPress already creates RSS feed endpoints for every standard WP post archive that you can access by adding /feed to the end of the URL. Have you confirmed that the ugly version of your URL works? ( if the ugly version aka index.php?... doesn't work then the pretty version will not work ) And have you installed one of the rewrite rule debugging/tester plugins, put in your expected URL, and confirmed that this rewrite rule is the top match? Did you flush your rewrite rules/resave permalinks? Your use of ^ at the beginning is highly unusual and doesn't occur in any of the docs

Thanks, @TomJNowell! Well, unfortunately not all sub pages of the event calender do have their own RSS feed. So we had to create it manually. And the first example above does work completely fine (it was done by our IT team). But I now I have to finish the second one on my own, at it does not work. And I do not get, why... Is it because it is more nested than the first one? And yes, I did flush. And yes, index.php?venue_category_feed_name=xyz does work as expected too.

Well, now I just made another and shorter rule: add_rewrite_rule('^events/xyz/([^/]+)/feed/?', 'index.php?venue_category_feed_name=$matches[1]', 'top'); and that does work fine...

I can't answer that, a rewrite analyser plugin would answer it though and tell you exactly why it doesn't work
